# Constructing Deterministic Trend and AR(1) and Forecasting in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to implement/generate a process using `arima.sim` like this:

$Y_t = a + b*t + \epsilon_t$, where $\epsilon_t = \phi\epsilon_{t-1}+\gamma_t$ a AR(1) process, where $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise.

And after this make the forecasting:

```
innovs <- rnorm(100,0,3)
x<-1:100 #time variable
mu<-10+.5*x #linear trend
y<-mu+arima.sim(length(x),innov=innovs, model=list(ar=0.7),sd=3)
plot.ts(y,main=expression(Trend+AR(1)),
        ylab=expression(Y[t]),xlab='Time',
        ,col='blue',lty=1,
        bty='l' )

plot(forecast(y,h=20))
grid(col='darkgrey',lwd=2)

forecastMA1<-Arima(window(y,end=y[46]),order=c(1,0,0),
                   include.drift=TRUE,include.constant=TRUE,include.mean=TRUE8,lambda=NULL)

plot(forecast(forecastMA1,h=54, level=99))
grid(col='darkgrey',lwd=2)
lines(y)
```

I hope the last graphic would bring to me the series closer to the forecast(blue) because is a trend stationary process, but it doesnt happen.

Is it right?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am slightly unclear what your question is however I am interpreting it
as,

> I expected better results from using the forecast method with a correctly
>   fitted ARIMA model

Firstly I would note your use of `window` seems a bit misleading. Since `window(y, end=y[46])`
returns `y` from values 1 to value  whatever `y[46]` is, rounded down. E.g.

```
> tt <- ts(2*(1:10))
> window(tt, end=3)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 3 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 2 4 6
> window(tt, end=tt[3])
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Frequency = 1 
[1]  2  4  6  8 10 12
```

It's hard to know what the performance of your charts looks like since you have
not set a seed for reproducibiliy, however what you are likely seeing is a
mis-estimation of the trend compounded over time. As a concrete example, look at the
following

```
> set.seed(42)
> N <- 1000
> innovs <- rnorm(N,0,3)
> x<-1:N #time variable
> mu<-10+.5*x #linear trend
> y<-mu+arima.sim(length(x),innov=innovs, model=list(ar=0.7),sd=3)
> 
> n <- 44
> forecastMA1b<-Arima(y[1:n],order=c(1,0,0), include.drift=TRUE,include.constant=TRUE)
> plot(forecast(forecastMA1b,h=N-n, level=99))
> grid(col='darkgrey',lwd=2)
> lines(y)
```

[image: AR1]

This looks fairly terrible, which is a result of errors in the trend compounding over time.
Repeating the above but settting `n <- 100` yields the following, which is clearly much improved

[image: AR2]

In response to your comment, it's not necessarily true that you cannot use this
model to forecast longer term trends, it's just that any estimation error in
the trend will become more apparent over time. Looking at the underlying estimated
model parameters in this context could be informative. From below we can see that in
the first model estimation the drift is estimated to be 0.3357 vs actual of 0.5 whereas
in the second estimate the drift is estimated to be 0.5007.

```
> n <- 44
> arma44 <-Arima(y[1:n],order=c(1,0,0), include.drift=TRUE,include.constant=TRUE)
> n <- 100
> arma100 <-Arima(y[1:n],order=c(1,0,0), include.drift=TRUE,include.constant=TRUE)
> arma44
Series: y[1:n] 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept   drift
      0.6665    13.0941  0.3357
s.e.  0.1090     2.7867  0.1055

sigma^2 estimated as 11.26:  log likelihood=-116
AIC=240.01   AICc=241.03   BIC=247.14
> arma100
Series: y[1:n] 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1  intercept   drift
      0.7093    10.1518  0.5007
s.e.  0.0689     2.0135  0.0342

sigma^2 estimated as 9.495:  log likelihood=-254.78
AIC=517.56   AICc=517.99   BIC=527.99
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now! I was not able to understand this difference that you showed. And thanks again for correct the code

Comment: The idea is that i only use this for short term forecasting.Right?And If my process is a random walk with drift plus error that follows an AR(1) process? The deterministic component will "dominate" my forecasting?

Comment: @DiogoBastos not necessarily, I have updated my answer to provide a bit more clarity